# Find the inverse of $θ:P(\Bbb{Z})→P(\Bbb{Z})$ defined as $θ(X) = \bar X$

Tags: inverse

Find the inverse of $θ:P(\Bbb{Z})→P(\Bbb{Z})$ defined as $θ(X) = \bar X$ (the complement of $X$)?

Would the inverse of the function just be the function itself?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please put more details in the body of the question. By that I mean, include the title in your body.

Comment: I can't get the bar to go right...

Comment: When you say \barX do you mean $\bar X$?  That usually denotes complex conjugate or else topological closure (in which case we need a topology).  When you say P(Z) do you mean polynomials in one variable with integer coefficients, or the power set of $\Bbb{Z}$ (the set of subsets of $\Bbb Z$), or something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean bar of X, or X compliment. I also mean the powerset of all integers, so what you said, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse function $\theta^{-1}$ is just the function $\theta$ itself, since the complement of the complement of a set $X$ is the set $X$ itself.  For example, the complement of $X=$ the set of even integers is the set of odd integers.  The complement of the latter set $\bar X$, i.e., the set of integers which are not odd, is the set of even integers $=X$.